# Getting parametrized type of concrete implementation of an interface with bounded type paramter. Java

Tags: java, generics, reflection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java reflection: Get concrete type of implemented generic interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7844610/java-reflection-get-concrete-type-of-implemented-generic-interface)

Say I have an interface:

```
public interface Monitor<T extends com.google.protobuf.Message>{
      public void checkMessage(T message)
}
```

and a concrete implementation:

```
public class MyMonitor implements Monitor<GeneratedMessage>{
      @Override
      public void checkMessage(GeneratedMessage message){
         //do something
      }
}
```

I want to write a utility method that I can pass MyMonitor to that will return GeneratedMessage.class. Is there any way to do this? I have seen a couple of blogs that are sort of related to this, but most of them are related to extended classes.

Also, if it is possible, can I declare  `Monitor<GeneratedMessage> monitor = new MyMonitor();` and pass monitor to the same method, and get GeneratedMessage back?

Comment: This looks helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/557663/retrieving-type-parameters-from-an-instance-of-a-generic-base-interface?rq=1: `MyMonitor.class.getGenericInterfaces()[0].getActualTypeArguments()`

Comment: Generic types are meant to be only a compile-time check, so there's no easy/obvious way (if it's possible at all) to write the utility method you want.  Maybe you can do it using reflection?  Either way, it sounds like you have a bigger design flaw that should be fixed.

Comment: Thilo's suggestion works great: http://ideone.com/5fOjp